# R shiny downloaded data has index added

Tags: r, shiny

In R Shiny, the data frame looks like below without the index.
[image: pic1]

However, after downloading the data, index column is automatically added to the data frame, please see below for illustration. How can I avoid this index being added? Because the downloaded template will be for user to populate the data, ideally would want no unnecessary fields.
[image: pic2]

My code for the download is listed below.

```
# UI
downloadButton("download1", "Download Template")

# reactive data frame df1 which contains other input from UI, can edit
# it to be a generic data frame for this to be reproducible 
  df1 = reactive({tibble(Year=strftime(seq(date_seq1(),
                                           date_seq2(),
                                           by = '1 week'), format = "%G"),
                         Week=strftime(seq(date_seq1(),
                                           date_seq2(),
                                           by = '1 week'), format = "%V"),
                         Date=seq(date_seq1(),
                                  date_seq2(),
                                  by = '1 week'),
                         !!input$urgency1 := "",
                         !!input$urgency2 := "",
                         !!input$urgency3 := "")})

  # download the data frame
  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){"user_template.csv"}, 
    content = function(file){
      write.csv(df1(), file)
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the option `row.names = FALSE` in the `write.csv` function.